# How do I add the same formula unique to each column in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to divide the values in each column and show the results in a third row. Can I apply a formula to automatically take the quotient of the top two rows in each column and output it as a percentage in the row below, without having to copy and paste the formula for each column?

Sorry if I'm not being clear; I'm not very well-versed in Google Sheets.

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, figured it out once I figured out the write wording to search lol. Just gotta type a formula and drag the bottom right of the cell to select the rest of the row; it converts the column in the original formula to the relevant one for the selected cell.

Comment: That is a way.... but there is another better :)

Go read up on using the `arrayformula()` function